# Does functional programming take up more memory?

Tags: memory, functional-programming

Warning! possibly a very dumb question

Does functional programming eat up more memory than procedural programming?
I mean ... if your objects(data structures whatever) are all imutable. Don't you end up having more object in the memory at a given time.

Doesn't this eat up more memory?

Comment: I don't think this is a dumb question at all. I'm very new to functional programming and I think this is a useful question to ask to help understand how functional programming works

Comment: See http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/ and decide for yourself. It's hard to make an apples to apples comparison, but the JVM functional languages (Scala, Clojure) do use more memory than regular Java. However, the JVM is not a normal case.

Comment: @Rafe Great link. It's interesting that while worse than Java (which is already one of the worst in terms of memory usage on those benchmarks) Scala isn't *that* much worse. In fact, JRuby, a non-functional language also built on the JVM, is *much* worse than Scala or Clojure.

Comment: The answer to this kind of question is usually: It depends on the program in question and the implementation. Regarding the latter: In the language shootout, Haskell - which has no mutability at all (and is radically non-strict unless forced to act otherwise) - takes significantly less memory than e.g. Java and slightly less than C# Mono for most benchmarks, because GHC is one hell of a compiler.

Comment: I don't know enough about the details to give a good answer, but just as a piece of additional information, one big way functional languages reduce memory usage is through sharing.  If you have a big structure, and then return a copy with a tiny piece modified, both big structures can reference the same values, and only the differences need to be copied.  This only works because values are pure.

Comment: https://softwaremill.com/persistent-data-structures-in-functional-programming/

Answer (score 12):

It depends on what you're doing. With functional programming you don't have to create defensive copies, so for certain problems it can end up using less memory.

Many functional programming languages also have good support for laziness, which can further reduce memory usage as you don't create objects until you actually use them. This is arguably something that's only correlated with functional programming rather than a direct cause, however.

Comment: With laziness, you don't create objects until you actually use them, but you keep all the necessary arguments in memory until you decide to create them. In a lot of cases, that plays against you.

Comment: @Pascal that's a good point. Which is better depends on which is going to be cheaper to hold on to: the inputs or the outputs of your computation.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves what do you mean by "defensive copies"? Can you give some example? I'm not used to this term. Thanks!

Comment: @GPrimola When you want to give read-only access to a mutable value you need to either create a defensive copy, or create a read-only view. They both have their trade-offs (a view is cheaper to make, but isn't inherently thread safe, for example). There are many pages that talk about defensive copying. Here is one: https://javacreed.com/what-is-defensive-copying

Answer (score 7):

Persistent values, that functional languages encourage but which can be implemented in an imperative language, make sharing a no-brainer.

Although the generally accepted idea is that with a garbage collector, there is some amount of wasted space at any given time (already unreachable but not yet collected blocks), in this context, without a garbage collector, you end up very often **copying** values that are immutable and could be shared, just because it's too much of a mess to decide who is responsible for freeing the memory after use.

These ideas are expanded on a bit in [this experience report](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/%7Eclk800/rand-test-study/_erofaisaf/erofaisaf-2009-10-8-12-02-00.pdf) which does not claim to be an objective study but only anecdotal evidence.

Comment: As of 2023-06-13 the link is broken

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz I should put this on HAL instead of linking to someone's personal copy but I don't have the energy. Anyway, fixed for now.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from avoiding defensive copies by the programmer, a very smart implementation of pure functional programming languages like Haskell or Standard ML (which lack physical pointer equality) can actively recover sharing of structurally equal values in memory, e.g. as part of the memory management and garbage collection.

Thus you can have automatic *hash consing* provided by your programming language runtime-system.

Compare this with objects in Java: *object identity* is an integral part of the language definition.  Even just exchanging one immutable `String` for another poses semantic problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed at least a tendency to regard memory as affluent ressource (which, in fact, it really is in most cases), but this applies to modern programming as a whole.

With multiple cores, parallel garbage collectors and available RAM in the gigabytes, one used to concentrate on different aspects of a program than in earlier times, when every byte one could save counted. Remember when Bill Gates said "640K should be enough for every program"?

Comment: Absolutely irrational argument. RAM is always a scarce resource. Have you ever heard about matrices? Imagine one with size 1k x 1k.And then 1m x 1m. Your GB will still fall short by far.

Comment: Beg your pardon, @sajid, but this was not a moral judgement or a claim that squandering memory was rational. It was simply a description of what happens in the REAL WORLD. You and I may not like it that an average web page nowadays is measured in the megabytes, but it's simply reality.

Comment: When it comes to handling huge amount of data, the size of the volatile memory does not count as much as the way you code works.

on any machine the first byte read from a lower level of memory, is the one coursing the delay, if your machine has k byte of RAM, and it read a cache line every time it access harddisk memory, you should not feel a thing. The compiler will cleverly rearrange the instructions such that any load operation not dependent on current evaluation will be moved to any unused space of computation. as long as the cache line is not longer than k bytes it should be fine

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm a lot late on this question.

Functional languages does not in general use more memory than imperative or OO languages. It depends more on the code you write. Yes F#, SML, Haskell and such has immutable values (not variables), but for all of them it goes without saying that if you update f.x. a single linked list, it re-compute only what is necessary.

Say you got a list of 5 elements, and you are removing the first 3 and adding a new one in front of it. it will simply get the pointer that points to the fourth element and let the new list point to that point of data i.e. reusing data. as seen below.

```
old list
    [x0,x1,x2] 
              \
               [x3,x4]
new list      /
       [y0,y1]
```

If it was an imperative language we could not do this because the values x3 and x4 could very well change over time, the list [x3,x4] could change too. Say that the 3 elements removed are not used afterward, the memory they use can be cleaned up right away, in contrast to unused space in an array.

That all data are immutable (except IO) are a strength. It simplifies the data flow analysis from a none trivial computation to a trivial one. This combined with a often very strong type system, will give the compiler a bunch of information about the code it can use to do optimization it normally could not do because of indicability. Most often the compiler turn values that are re-computed recursively and discarded from each iteration (recursion) into a mutable computation. These two things gives you the proof that if your program compile it will work. (with some assumptions)

If you look at the language Rust (not functional) just by learning about "borrow system" you will understand more about how and when things can be shared safely. it is a language that is painful to write code in unless you like to see your computer scream at you that your are an idiot. Rust is for the most part the combination of all the study made of programming language and type theory for more than 40 years. I mention Rust, because it despite the pain of writing in it, has the promise that if your program compile, there will be NO memory leaking, dead locking, dangling pointers, even in multi processing programs. This is because it uses much of the research of functional programming language that has been done.

For a more complex example of when functional programming uses less memory, I have made a lexer/parser interpreter (the same as generator but without the need to generate a code file) when computing the states of the DFA (deterministic finite automata) it uses immutable sets, because it compute new sets of already computed sets, my code allocate less memory simply because it borrow already known data points instead of copying it to a new set.

To wrap it up, yes functional programming can use more memory than imperative once. Most likely it is because you are using the wrong abstraction to mirror the problem. i.e. If you try to do it the imperative way in a functional language it will hurt you.

Try this book, it has not much on memory management but is a good book to start with if you will learn about compiler theory and yes it is legal to download. I have ask Torben, he is my old professor.
[http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/~torbenm/Basics/](http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/%7Etorbenm/Basics/)

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my hat in the ring here. The short answer to the question is no, and this is because *immutability* does not mean the same thing as *stored in memory*. For example, let's take this toy program :

```
x = 2
x = x * 3
x = x * 2
print(x)
```

Which uses mutation to compute new values. Compare this to the same program which does not use mutation:

```
x = 2
y = x * 3
z = y * 2
print(z)
```

At first glance, it appears this requires 3x the memory of the first program! However, just because a value is *immutable* doesn't mean it needs to be *stored in memory*. In the case of the second program, after `y` is computed, `x` is no longer necessary, because it isn't used for the rest of the program, and can be *garbage collected*, or removed from memory. Similarly, after `z` is computed, `y` can be garbage collected. So, in principle, with a perfect garbage collector, after we execute the third line of code, I only need to have stored `z` in memory.

Another oft-worried about source of memory consumption in functional languages is deep recursion. For example, calculating a large Fibonacci number.

```
calc_fib(x):
    if x > 1:
        return x * calc_fib(x-1)
    else:
        return x
```

If I run `calc_fib(100000)`, I *could* implement this in a way which requires storing 100000 values in memory, or I could use Tail-Call Elimination (basically storing only the most-recently computed value in memory instead of all function calls). For less straightforward recursion you can resort to trampolining. So for functional languages which support this, recursion does not need to be a source of massive memory consumption, either. However, not all nominally functional languages do (for example, JavaScript does not).